# How can we index multi array of object parameter in our input?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set course attribute from parameter to my input so that I can be able the insert the value on it but I cannot access the course attribute. ends_level and course becomes any instead of string means I haven't indexed properly the ends_level which the array of object course. I really need your eyes to see something that have missed or missed up. I hope I have explained it well. Thanks in advance y'all.

```
import { React, useState, useEffect }  from 'react';
// Bootstrap Component
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { TextField  } from '@material-ui/core';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { updateProfile } from '../../../actions/profile';

const Profile = ({ data }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const currentId = data._id;
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState(
        {
            profile: {
                name: "",
            },
            skills: [
                {
                    end: "",
                    ends_level: [
                        {
                            course: "",
                            level: ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ],
                
        }
    );

    const profile = useSelector((state) => currentId ? state.profile.find((p) => p._id === currentId) : null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(profile) setPostData(profile);
    }, [profile])

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(currentId) {
            dispatch(updateProfile(currentId, postData));
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                
        <TextField
        value={postData.profile.name}
        onChange={(e) => 
            setPostData(
                {
                    ...postData, profile:
                    {
                        ...postData.profile, name: e.target.value
                    } 
                }
            )
        }
        />

        <TextField
        onChange={(e) =>
            setPostData(
                {
                    ...postData, skills:
                    {
                        ...postData.skills, ends_level:
                            {
                                ...postData.skills.ends_level, course: e.target.value
                            }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        />
        
        <Button variant="primary" size="md" type="submit" block >Save</Button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: You have initialized the postData.skills as an array but while updating you are setting it as a dict

Comment: @Jayanth Hi, can you add your answer please